# Is there an easy way to put the linear regression equation in the plot?

Tags: r, plot, graph

I'm new into R-language, since my field is quantitative chemistry i would really like to start improving myself and aiming to work on R for my future lab reports as an student. I've search about that in this place but find it really difficult to understand who to just simply align the L.R equation into the graph. Is there an easy way to make that without ggplot2? or at least there's a place where i can go and learn about "stylizing" graphs. Thanks in advance :D

[image]

This is the code that goes in Gosser's R for Quantitative Chemistry book. I understand the logic behind it but when it comes to put text or customized the graphs i go blank.
[image]

Comment: Please do not post (only) an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly into a [code block].

Comment: Please make this question *reproducible*. This includes sample code you've attempted (including listing non-base R packages, and any errors/warnings received), sample *unambiguous* data (e.g., `data.frame(x=...,y=...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))` into a [code block]), and intended output given that input. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Comment: Here is a link https://intro2r.com/baseplot_start.html

Comment: While @Dave2e did provide you a reference to get you going styling graphs. I will say that if you're going to do more than a few plots you might be better off trying to learn one of the many libraries for plotting (such as ggplot2 or plotly).  If you want to make the most basic of plots, base R is definitely the easiest way to plot. While base R plotting is capable of many things, in terms of customization and versatility, the learning curve for base R is probably a lot steeper than many of the libraries designed for plotting.